# insert into wp database not working

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm using following code for inserting form data into wp database. But it returns "page not found" whenever I submit any value.

```html
<?php global $wpdb; if(isset($_POST[ "submit"])){ $wpdb->insert( "wp_test_form", array( "name" =>$name, "email" => $email, )); } ?>



<form action="" id="postjob" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: in your example, the action=" "  should have your current page URL

Comment: @RaresHideg That's unnecessary and not the problem. An empty action parameter tells the browser to post to the submitting page.

Comment: @EdCottrell you should be right, but submitting a form that redirects to a 404 page means that the form is not submitting to the current page. maybe there is a condition before the page that triggers and redirects.

Comment: @RaresHideg Something's wrong, yes, but I'm 100% sure that's not it.

Comment: The problem, as explained in the linked duplicate, is that your form field names (`name` and `email`) are reserved by Wordpress. Wordpress effectively "hijacks" the submission and tries to handle it, cutting your page out of the process. Rename your fields.

Comment: Also, for future reference, searching either Google or this site for "wordpress form post 404" turns up a lot of hits with this solution.